# What's wrong with this php foreaach code?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);

$menus = 'SELECT menus FROM menus';

foreach($db->query($menus) as $row ){
  echo "<li class=\"main\"> $row['mainLink'] $row['menus'] </a> </li>";
}
```

`$row['mainLink']` is equal to `<a href='yada yada.php'>`.

`$row['menus']` is equals to `yada yada`.

The code give me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\yada-yada\index.php on line 34
```

Comment: Use string concatenation or curly braces, like: `echo "<li class=\"main\"> {$row['mainLink']} {$row['menus']} </a> </li>";`

Comment: Doesn't " " (double quotes) know how to read variables?

Comment: "Doesn't " " (double quotes) know how to read variables?" Yes, but not array variables where you're specifiying the key. You could use "String {$var['key']} More string". Or the above suggestions is probabaly the better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `$row['mainlink']` inside a string `""`.

Try either `" . $row['mainLink'] . "` or `{$row['mainLink']}`

Comment: Or $row[mainLink] with no quotes

Comment: Your solution gives me this error -> Notice: Undefined index: mainLink in C:\xampp\htdocs\yada-yada\index.php on line 34

Comment: If your query is really the one you posted, it is normal. You are selecting only `menus` column and trying to retrieve `mainLink` one. You have to add `mainLink` in select clause as well.

Comment: "Doesn't " " (double quotes) know how to read variables?" Yes, but not array variables where you're specifiying the key. You could use "String {$var['key']} More string". Or the above suggestions is probabaly the better one.

Comment: Shoot, I forgot to select the mainLink. Oh, and btw, it still gives me an error if I use double quotes, but single quotes doesn't

Comment: What's with the curly braces? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess following code should work

```
printf('<li class="main">%s %s</a></li>', $row['mainLink'], $row['menus']);
```